# Filtering results of a function takes much longer than filtering on the same query without a function

Tags: sql, optimization, sql-function

I have a function named `LocalItems`, with a `@LanguageID` parameter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LocalItems] 
(   
    @LanguageID INT
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT Items.*, Products.Name, Products.BrandID
    FROM Items
    INNER JOIN LocalProducts(@LanguageID) AS Products
        ON Items.ProductID = Products.ID 
)
```

When I apply a filter to the results of the function:

```
SELECT *
FROM LocalItems(0)
WHERE BrandID IN(50,51) AND ID < 3500
```

the resulting query takes 12 minuutes (!!!) to return some 3500 records. When I run the query directly:

```
SELECT Items.*, Products.Name, Products.BrandID
FROM Items
INNER JOIN LocalProducts(3) AS Products
    ON Items.ProductID = Products.ID 
WHERE BrandID IN(50,51) AND ID < 3500
```

the query takes something like 5 seconds to execute.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What about the `IIF` and the `ROWNUMBER`?

Answer (score 0):

The big differences:

1. Your table is indexed but your function result (table) is not.
2. Your table applies the filter (while clause) before the join.  So it only joins 3500 rows.  Your function result, will contain all rows, then it will join, and then filter.

You would get a big gain, if you passed your filter criteria into your function, so you returned a smaller result set.

You would also get a big gain if you created a table variable for returning results and put an index on columns `BranchID` and `ID`.  This sounds like a lot of work, but it would solve both of your performance problems, (if you still want to stick with the table function.